# I now have gone through all the forums but still cant get my Php to send data to my database for commenting system

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been up for 12 hours trying to get  data to send to my database - I connect to the server no problem when I run comments.db.php, but I cannot get the form data to show up in phpmyadmin. I have tried changing the code to backticks in the comments.inc.php file. I can click submit fine and there are no errors, but nothing is showing up in the table I created.

This is the beginning of my index file

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
include 'comments.dbh.php:';
include 'comments.inc.php';


?>
```

Here is the form in the index file

```
  <?php

    echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($mysqli)."'>
    <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
    <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
    </form>"

    ?>
```

Here is the comments.inc.php file

```
function setComments($mysqli) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit']))  {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];


            $mysqli = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('".$uid."', '".$date."', '".$message."')";


        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqli);
    }

mysqli_close();

}
```

I tried changing the above to the following but that didn't work either. I also tried backticks and nothing.

```
$mysqls = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
```

Here is my comments.dbh.php file

```
<?php


$username=""; - These are filled out but I left them blank 
$password="";
$database="london34_commentsection";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

$mysqli->select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

?>
```

[This is my phpMyAdmin Screenshot listing my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGgj.png)

If anyone could offer any guidance I would greatly appreciate it. Like I said, ive gone through a lot of the posts on the topic on here and just cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function is not returning any value so it's useless 
I edited the code and did this 
index file form

```
<?php

    echo "<form method='POST' action='comments.inc.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='Anonymous'>
    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
    <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
    </form>"
?>
```

make sure all your files are in the same folder 
comments.inc.php

```
 if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit']))  {
        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];


            $mysqli = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('".$uid."', '".$date."', '".$message."')";


        $result = mysqli_query($sqli,$mysqli);
    }
```

and I don't know, where did you defined `$sqli?`
comments.dbh.php file

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="london34_comments";
$sqli = mysqli_connect('localhost',$username,$password,$database);

?>
```

let me know the errors in the comments.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I am not sure why but $sqli must have been cut off - It was supposed to read like this

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

$mysqli->select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

?>

I will try your edits!

Comment: @MarkMitchell try my edits and let me know all the errors

Comment: Hi - Thank you again for the edits - I replaced the code and although it did not return any errors, now when I click submit - www.LondonOntarioMortgages.ca/test/blog.php it goes directly to a blank screen - and the database did not receive anything

Comment: go to your comments.dbh.php file and see if it's blank. if it is then tell me @MarkMitchell

Comment: Yes it is - it was returning an error when I could not connect - since it stopped the error I figured it was logging in

Comment: how come the url is blog.php and not comments.inc.php ?

Comment: The blog.php is where I have my html and where i"ll be wanting to put in my comment section - I am trying to set up a comment system on an already exhisting page - www.LondonOntarioMortgages.ca

Comment: @MarkMitchell in the comments.inc.php change this line `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqli);` to `$result = mysqli_query($sqli,$mysqli);`

Comment: @jedgar - thank you again - I tried and it is still going to blank screen with nothing showing up in the table in the database. I really do appreciate all of your effort - I hate to be a pain.

Comment: I will not leave you like this.@MarkMitchell wanna chat and do it some where else? like on facebook?

Comment: @jedgar - I'd love to right now but just sitting down for dinner - Thank you though! Maybe another time?

Comment: How would I find you on FB?

Comment: tell me your name @MarkMitchell